# How to keep WSL running after locking your PC or switching the screen off?

Tags: windows-11, freeze, wsl2, logoff

I want to keep some code running for a while on my Windows 11 computer with WSL2.
However, if I hit Win+L to lock the computer or switch the screen off, the WSL seems to just freeze and resumes only after I log back into my computer.
How can I prevent this?
(I need to switch the screen off if I'm going to sleep or if I'm leaving my computer unattended in the office.)

Comment: You will have to provide more information since this is a known issue in specific builds of [WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10285)

Comment: I wonder it has anything to do with "modern standby" (in case your machine supports it).

Comment: I am experiencing the same on Windows 10. But it only happens sometimes, not always.